# PS Azure Web App Exception calling “UploadFile” with “2” argument(s): “The Content-Type header cannot be set to a multipart type for this request

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Hi I am trying to upload published files from Azure Git artifacts to FTP. But randomly I am getting the below error.

**This is only happening for files not for any folder or subfolders.**

“UploadFile” with “2” argument(s): “The Content-Type header cannot be set to a multipart type for this request.

All the files are available in the artifacts.

Observation & tried:

1. All files are present in artifacts
2. Getting the error only for files. (Folder & subfolders are creating successfully)
3. Stopped the Web App and then tried to upload
4. Tried Sleep also between uploading two files

After all of these, the result is the same.

Can anyone please help me out?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $target_directory

        # Upload files recursively 
        write-host "target_directory - $target_directory"
        Set-Location $target_directory
        $webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
        $webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
        
        $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $target_directory -Recurse
        write-host 'Uploading started............................'
        foreach ($file in $files)
        {
            write-host "file -" + $file.FullName
            if($file.FullName -match "web.config" -or $file.FullName -match ".pdb" -or $file.FullName -match "roslyn" -or $file.FullName -match "obj\Debug"){
                write-host "ignoring " + $file.FullName
                continue
            }
            $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')  
            $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
            write-host "uri -" + $uri.AbsoluteUri
            write-host '--------'
            if($file.PSIsContainer)
            {
                write-host 'PSIsContainer - All dir/files within' $file
                
                get-childitem -path $file -Recurse
                
                try
                {
                    $makeDirectory = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri);
                    $makeDirectory.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password);
                    $makeDirectory.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::MakeDirectory;
                    $makeDirectory.GetResponse();

                    #folder created successfully
                }
                catch [Net.WebException] 
                {
                    try 
                    {

                        #if there was an error returned, check if folder already existed on server
                        $checkDirectory = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($uri);
                        $checkDirectory.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password);
                        $checkDirectory.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::PrintWorkingDirectory;
                        $response = $checkDirectory.GetResponse();
                        $response.StatusDescription
                        #folder already exists!
                    }
                    catch [Net.WebException] 
                    {               
                        #if the folder didn't exist, then it's probably a file perms issue, incorrect credentials, dodgy server name etc
                    }   
                }
                continue
            }

            try{
                write-host "Uploading to " $uri.AbsoluteUri " from " $file.FullName
                $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
                start-sleep -Seconds 1
            }
            catch{
                ##[error]Error message
                Write-Host "##[error]Error in uploading " $file  -ForegroundColor red
                Write-Host $_
                $disputedFiles  = $disputedFiles  + $file.FullName
                $_file = @{
                    FileName = $file.FullName
                    FTPPath = $uri.AbsoluteUri 
                }
                $_o = New-Object psobject -Property $_file; 
                $disputedFilesList = $disputedFilesList + $_o
            }
        } 

        Write-Host "##[debug] Starting uploading the disputed files....."
        foreach($file in $disputedFilesList){
            try{
                write-host "Uploading to " $file.FTPPath " from " $file.FileName
                $webclient.UploadFile($file.FTPPath, $file.FileName)
                start-sleep -Seconds 1
            }
            catch{
                write-host "##[error]Error(2) in uploading to " $file.FTPPath " from " $file.FileName
            }
        }
        Write-Host "##[debug] Ending uploading the disputed files....."

        remove-item -path $target_directory\* -Recurse
        get-childitem -path $target_directory
        write-host "Directory Empty after cleanup"

$webclient.Dispose()
```

Comment: Can you use `copy-item/move-item` instead?

Comment: can you please share any reference links? I am not so fast coder in powershell.